# Async function loops once while inserting data into database (Xamarin Forms - SQLite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been learning C# and Xamarin Forms recently and have come across a problem when inserting data into my database and then refreshing my CollectionView.

These are the involved methods in my ViewModel:

```
        async Task AddProductItem()
        {
            await ProductItemService.AddItem(NewProductInputValue, "IndianRed", false);
            await Refresh();

        } 

        async Task Refresh()
        {

            IsBusy = true;
            ProductItems.Clear();

            var items = await ProductItemService.GetItem();

            ProductItems.AddRange(items);
            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

The database service works without any issues. The problem lays within the async functions. After calling AddProductItem(), sometimes the method Refresh() will "loop" and the data will be shown twice on my model. I've tried calling the Database Service synchronously, but either I did it wrongly or it isn't the solution, because it still happens.

Here's some examples:

[After calling the AddProductItem() method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KpBp.png) (Note that this just happens "randomly". I've tried to find a pattern but I didn't find any, sometimes it works the intended way 5 times in a row and sometimes it messes up 10 times in a row.)

[After manually refreshing, the data is shown correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOu37.png) The data is retrieved without issues, the problem has to be with the async functions.

I also tried with Task.Delay() within the Refresh() method, but even after adding a 5 second delay, it still didn't solve it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere in your code. Something is causing a function to be called twice. You'll have to add to question enough code that someone can see what is happening.  **1)** Show all code that calls those two functions. **2)** Print `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` at start of `Refresh`. OR  Debug.WriteLine calls at start of various functions, to see if any other functions are called twice.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that the problem not the async function loops once.

In your view model, the ItemSource seems be a `List<>()`, I don't know how do you notify the UI to update when you add and remove the item in the List. But you can change the `ProductItems.Clear();` in the `async Task Refresh()` to the `ProductItems = new List<>();`.

In addition, you can try to use the `ObservableCollection<>` instead of the `List<>` in your viewmodel.

Just like the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding